# Afirmar si una posición de la matriz es punto de silla

Tags: c

Estoy intentando un programa que, pasando una posición de la matriz, afirme si esa posición es punto de silla de dicha matriz (es el menor valor de su fila, y a la vez  el mayor de su columna).

El problema es que en algunas posiciones que no son puntos de silla sí dice que sí es punto de silla, y en otras que no lo son, lo niega. Por lo que estoy confuso con mi programa.

Dejo el código por si alguien pudiera ayudarme:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
#define M 4

int puntoSilla(int mat[N][M], int posFila, int posColumna);
void escribeMat(int mat[N][M]);

void main()
{
    int mat[N][M]=
    { 3, 4, 5, 3,
      2, 3, 2, 2,
      1, 2, 0, 1, //el punto de silla esta en la posicion 2-1
    }, posFila=2, posColumna=1;

    printf("\n");
    escribeMat(mat);
    if(puntoSilla(mat, posFila, posColumna)==1)
        printf("Tiene punto de silla en la posicion %d-%d", posFila, posColumna);
    else printf("No hay punto de silla");
}


int puntoSilla(int mat[N][M], int posFila, int posColumna)
{
    int i, j, enc=0;

    for(i=0; i<N && !enc; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<M && !enc; j++)
        {
            if(mat[posColumna][posFila]>mat[posFila][j] && mat[posColumna][posFila]<mat[i][posColumna])
            enc=1;
        }
    }

    return enc;

}

void escribeMat(int mat[N][M])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda será muy agradecida. Gracias.

Comment: Parece que hay cierta confusión entre lo que es fila y lo que es columna, y también en el concepto de punto de silla en sí (2-1 no es punto de silla según la definición dada en la pregunta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionaba en el comentario, parece que hay cierta confusión en tu código que necesitas aclarar antes de seguir adelante con la programación: ¿qué es N y qué es M?¿Cuál es la fila y cuál la columna? Por ejemplo, vamos a ver el `if` de la función `puntoSilla` para destacar la confusión:

```
if(mat[posColumna][posFila]>mat[posFila][j] && mat[posColumna][posFila]<mat[i][posColumna])
```

Si te fijas en la primera comparación, según el primer valor (`mat[posColumna][posFila]`), la columna es N y la fila es M; pero el segundo valor (`mat[posFila][j]`) la fila es N y la columna es M. Igual ocurre con la segunda comparación, donde el primera valor es `mat[posColumna][posFila]` (la columna es N y la fila es M) y se compara con `mat[i][posColumna]` donde la fila es N y la columna es M. Ese es el **primer error: en algunos sitios se compara filas con columnas (y viceversa) en lugar de filas con filas y columnas con columnas**.

La solución es sencilla. Mirando como está estructurado el código y los valores de N y M, N es la fila y M es la columna, lo que hace que el `if` fuese algo como esto (simplemente asegúrate de que el primer índice sea la fila y el segundo la columna):

```
if(mat[posFila][posColumna]>mat[posFila][j] || mat[posFila][posColumna]<mat[i][posColumna])
```

> Nota: fijate que también cambia de `&&` a `||`; La explicación a continuación.

La función `puntoSilla` también es interesante porque contiene un **segundo error: de primeras se asume que no es el punto de silla y se intenta demostrar que sí lo es, ¡cuando debería hacerse lo contrario!** Tal y como está ahora, en cuanto se encuentra un valor que no cumple la regla del punto de silla, se devuelve un 1 que quiere decir que ese punto sí es el punto de silla.

Solucionando esos dos problemas, el código ya funciona y quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
#define M 4

int puntoSilla(int mat[N][M], int posFila, int posColumna);
void escribeMat(int mat[N][M]);

int main()
{
    int mat[N][M] = {
        3, 4, 5, 3,
        2, 3, 2, 2,
        1, 2, 0, 1  };
    int posFila=2, posColumna=1;

    printf("\n");

    escribeMat(mat);

    // comparo todas las posiciones del array para ver si son punto de silla
    for (posFila = 0; posFila < N; posFila++)
        for (posColumna = 0; posColumna < M; posColumna++)
            if(puntoSilla(mat, posFila, posColumna)==1)
                printf("Tiene punto de silla en la posicion %d-%d\n", posFila, posColumna);
            else
                printf("No hay punto de silla en la posicion %d-%d\n", posFila, posColumna);

    return 0;
}


int puntoSilla(int mat[N][M], int posFila, int posColumna)
{
    int i, j, noenc=1;

    for(i=0; i<N && noenc; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<M && noenc; j++)
        {
            if(mat[posFila][posColumna]>mat[posFila][j] || mat[posFila][posColumna]<mat[i][posColumna]) {
                noenc=0;
            }
        }
    }

    return noenc;
}

void escribeMat(int mat[N][M])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<M; j++) {
            printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

> Nota: Una posible mejora, especialmente para matrices grandes sería no anidar los bucles `for`: ahora mismo estás realizando innecesariamente N*M comparaciones si el valor es el punto de silla. Si compararas sólo la fila y sólo la columna, estarías haciendo N+M comparaciones. Puede que para una matriz de 3x4 no sea mucho (12 vs 7 comparaciones), pero si la matriz fuese más grande, como por ejemplo de 1.000 x 1.000, sí que habría diferencia (1.000.000 vs 2.000 comparaciones en ese caso). No he hecho este cambio en el código para dejarlo lo más parecido a lo que tenías originalmente.