# ¿Cómo encontrar el punto de silla de la matriz?

Tags: algoritmos, delphi, matrices

Es necesario encontrar el punto de silla de la matriz, la cual es llenada por el usuario mediante el teclado.

En el siguiente código está el formato de la matriz, en el cual se pueda añadir o eliminar filas y columnas de acuerdo como quiera el usuario. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para ingresar los elementos y encontrar el punto de silla?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, StdCtrls, Grids;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Label1: TLabel;
        Label2: TLabel;
        Edit1: TEdit;
        Edit2: TEdit;
        Button1: TButton;
        Button2: TButton;
        StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Edit1.Text:='3';
      Edit2.Text:='3';
      Button1Click(Sender);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var i,N,M:integer;
    begin
      N:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
      M:=StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
      for i:=1 To N Do
        StringGrid1.Cells[i,0]:=IntToStr(i);
      for i:=1 To M Do
        StringGrid1.Cells[0,i]:=IntToStr(i);
        StringGrid1.ColCount:=N+1;
        StringGrid1.RowCount:=M+1;
        StringGrid1.Cells[0,0]:='Matrix';
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: ¿Has buscado en SOes? Hay otra pregunta sobre cómo averiguar si es un punto de silla que podría ser de ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando como referencia la [respuesta de Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9054/21) a la pregunta [Afirmar si una posición de la matriz es punto de silla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/9018/21) en lenguaje `C`, y tomando en cuenta que el usuario ingresaría los valores en un StringGrid, tal como lo planteas en la pregunta, vamos a realizar la solución en varios pasos.

1. Definición (tomada de la [pregunta de marras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/9018/21): Un punto de silla

   > es el menor valor de su fila, y a la vez el mayor de su columna
2. Declaro un tipo de dato para almacenar la matriz de enteros:

   ```
    type
      TIntArray = array of Integer;
      TIntArray2 = array of TIntArray;
   ```
3. Declaro un método para extraer los datos del `StringGrid` y cargarlos en una variable de tipo `TIntArray2`. Esto minimiza las conversiones entre string/entero y lanza un error si el usuario no ha ingresado correctamente la matriz.

   ```
    procedure TForm1.ExtraerMatrizDeGrid(var Matriz: TIntArray2);
    var
      I, J: Integer;
    begin
      SetLength(Matriz, StringGrid1.RowCount - 1);
      for I := 0 to High(Matriz) do
        SetLength(Matriz[I], StringGrid1.ColCount - 1);
      for I := 0 to High(Matriz) do
        for J := 0 to High(Matriz[I]) do
          Matriz[I][J] := StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[J + 1, I + 1]);
    end;
   ```

   Es importante tomar en cuenta que, en la solución, la primera dimensión de la matriz son las filas y la segunda las columnas.
4. Declaro un método que tiene una sub-función que determina si una posición dada es un punto de silla, en base a la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9054/21) ya referida. El método recorre la matriz dada como parámetro buscando puntos de silla y al encontrarlos, añade una línea a un memo indicando las coordenadas del mismo.

   ```
    procedure TForm1.EncontrarPuntoSilla(const Matriz: TIntArray2);

      function EsPuntoSilla(posFila, posColumna: Integer): Boolean;
      var
        I, J: Integer;
        RowCount, ColCount: Integer;
      begin
        Result := True;
        RowCount := Length(Matriz);
        ColCount := Length(Matriz[0]);
        for I := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
        begin
          if (Matriz[posFila, posColumna] < Matriz[I, posColumna]) then
          begin
            Result := False;
            break;
          end;
          for J := 0 to ColCount - 1 do
            if (Matriz[posFila, posColumna] > Matriz[posFila, J]) then
            begin
              Result := False;
              break;
            end;
          if not Result then
            Break;
        end;
      end;

    var
      I, J: Integer;
    begin
      for I := 0 to Length(Matriz) - 1 do
        for J := 0 to Length(Matriz[I]) - 1 do
          if EsPuntoSilla(I, J) then
            Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('La posición %d,%d es un punto silla, valor: %d'
              , [I + 1, J + 1, Matriz[I, J]]));
    end;
   ```
5. Finalmente, en un manejador de evento OnClick de un botón, hago las llamadas necesarias para realizar la tarea:

   ```
    var
      Matriz: TIntArray2;
    begin
      ExtraerMatrizDeGrid(Matriz);
      EncontrarPuntoSilla(Matriz);
    end;
   ```

Así se ve en ejecución, ingresando los mismos valores del ejemplo dado en la pregunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]